# Fast Visualization in C

Tags: c, gtk, gnuplot, real-time, visualization

I am trying to visualize some 1D and 2D data which are the processed output of a sensor.

My project is written in `C` and I tried to make it as efficient as possible... However, with my current choice of `PLPlot` for visualization, plotting is taking too much time, even for several driver choices (`xwin`, `tcl/tk`, `qtwidget`...). I can see a 2D figure (800x800) being plotted column by column if I choose `xwin` for example! :P

Is there any way to speed that up while sticking to `PlPlot`? And what driver would you recommend?

If not, what other visualization tool would you recommend for my fast visualization task?

I read about `gnuplot_i` and `GTK+` for example but I have no idea about how fast they are and how easy it is for a beginner to integrate them in a C project. I was also recommended to use Qt... too bad it is only `C++` and doesn't have a `C` interface.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you are asking about `PLPlot` but as a suggestion, take a look at `QwtPlot`.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks for the suggestion... Any reason why I should use it instead of other options?

Comment: It's easy, and fast. You code the GUI part in C++ using the Qt framework. And for the it's only C++, that is nothing to worry about, you could use C code with C++ and they integrate easily. I don't like C++ but I like Qt, it is really cross-platform and very clear API.